# how to build predicate of Array.filter from string

Tags: javascript

I have an array and I want to build filter predicate from string

```
var testArray=[{Id:1,IsChecked:true},{Id:2,IsChecked:false},{Id:3,IsChecked:false}];
var predicate='IsChecked==true && Id<3'

var filteredArray= testArray.filter(i=>i ????predicate) ????
```

i have tried

```
//this works
var predicate='IsChecked==true'
var filterFunction=new Function("i","return i." + predicate)

//this throw an error (Id is not defined)
var predicate='IsChecked==true && Id<3'
var filterFunction=new Function("i","return i." + predicate)
```

how to build predicated from string?

any idea using other javascript libraries such as ramda and loadash is welcomed.

Comment: What other operators other than `===` needs to be supported for `predicate`?

Comment: I haven't met the use case of another operator yes. but it might be greater than or less than

Comment: I have shared an example with `==` and `<` operator. Have a look.

Answer (score 1):

To make from a string you need to use `eval` which is bad practice.

Instead `predicte` can be a function which takes an item and do the condition with it. You need just to pass this function into the `filter`.

```js
const testArray = [ 
   { Id:1, IsChecked: true},
   { Id:2, IsChecked: false}
];

const predicate = (item) => item.IsChecked == true;

const filteredArray = testArray.filter(predicate);

console.log(filteredArray);
```

Comment: yes can be a function but I want to build it from a string , suppose it is built in runtime by the user, not a developer.

Answer (score 0):

You can process a predicate into a function first.

```
function processPredicate( predicate )
{
   var items = predicate.split(/[\W$]+/); //split by a non word character including $ which can also be part of an identifier

   //if the operand if all numbers, then parse them into a number
   var operand1 = parseToNative( items[0] );
   var operand2 = parseToNative( items[1] );

   var operator = predicate.match(/[\W$]+/)[0];
   var fReturn = () => false;
   switch (operator)
   {
      case "<":
         fReturn = (obj) => obj[operand1] < operand2;
         break;
      case ">":
         fReturn = (obj) => obj[operand1] > operand2;
         break;
      case "<=":
         fReturn = (obj) => obj[operand1] <= operand2;
         break;
      case ">=":
         fReturn = (obj) => obj[operand1] >= operand2;
         break;
      case "==":
         fReturn = (obj) => obj[operand1] == operand2;
         break;
      case "===":
      default:
         fReturn = (obj) => obj[operand1] === operand2;
   }
   return fReturn;
}
```

**Demo**

```js
function parseToNative( val )
{
   return  isNaN( val ) ? (val == "true" || val == "false" ? val === "true" : val ) : Number(val);
}

function processPredicate( predicate )
{
   var items = predicate.split(/[\W$]+/); //split by a non word character including $ which can also be part of an identifier
   
   //if the operand if all numbers, then parse them into a number
   var operand1 = parseToNative( items[0] );
   var operand2 = parseToNative( items[1] );
   
   var operator = predicate.match(/[\W$]+/)[0];
   var fReturn = () => false;
   switch (operator)
   {
      case "<":
         fReturn = (obj) => obj[operand1] < operand2;
         break;
      case ">":
         fReturn = (obj) => obj[operand1] > operand2;
         break;
      case "<=":
         fReturn = (obj) => obj[operand1] <= operand2;
         break;
      case ">=":
         fReturn = (obj) => obj[operand1] >= operand2;
         break;
      case "==":
         fReturn = (obj) => obj[operand1] == operand2;
         break;
      case "===":
      default:
         fReturn = (obj) => obj[operand1] === operand2;
   }
   //console.log( operand1, operand2, operator, fReturn );
   return fReturn;
}

var testArray=[{Id:1,IsChecked:true},{Id:2,IsChecked:false}];
var predicate1=processPredicate('IsChecked==true')
var predicate2=processPredicate('Id<2')

var output = testArray.filter( function(item){
  return Object.keys( item ).some( s => predicate1( item ) );
})
console.log( output );

output = testArray.filter( function(item){
  return Object.keys( item ).some( s => predicate2( item ) );
})
console.log( output );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [VM2](https://github.com/patriksimek/vm2) for this. It is essentially a safe eval replacement which is perfect for this type of work.

Create a function wrapper as an es6 template string, inject your predicate into the function body and return it. When you vm.run that function, I'll give you the actual predicate function you need.

Bonus: you can even create a locked down sandbox environment with VM2 if your user input is not trusted, so your code can not access outside of the current context.